# How to get current locale so as to display correct data in data-view webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, xslt

I am making data-view which gets data from a list (having different language columns).

My problem is I want to get the current user locale in XSLT and then display data from appropriate language column by comparing the LCID's.

Like if the LCID is 1033 display English conlumn in data-view.

Kindly suggest a way if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

SPContext.Current.Web.Locale

Or System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Or Request.UserLanguages